# What does $~ u(\cdot, t)$ mean when referring to a function?

Tags: functions, notation

I sometimes stumble over professors defining a function $u$ using regular ([but quite sloppy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6876/161)) notation like  $u(x,t) = A\sin(x)e^{-kt}$. Later in their notes, they state something like

$u(\cdot, t)$ = ...

What does the $\cdot$ in this notation mean? Why not just write $u(x,t)$ as before?

Comment: What was the context?

Comment: In statistics, the dot indicates, summation. It seems like $\int_{x}u(x,t)dx$ to me. I might be off-though I feel it to be so. The context does matter.

Comment: The $\cdot$ is effectively a placeholder. Yes, it's lazy, but it's quite common...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This indicates that we are  viewing $u$ as a function of the first variable only, with the second variable fixed at $t$.

Another way to say this is that if $u$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then $u(\cdot,t)$ is another name for the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which we might define by $f(x) = u(x,t)$.