# Function notation terminology

Tags: functions, terminology

Given the function $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, $X$ is called the domain while $Y$ is called the codomain. But what do you call $f(x)=x^2$ in this context, where $x\in X$? That is to say - what is the name for the $f(x)$ notation?

And while I'm here, what is the proper way to write a function like this? Would it be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\;f(x)=x^2$?

---

Edit:

I figured I'd add this to add a bit of context into why I'm asking. I'm writing a set of notes in LaTeX, and I'd like to use the correct terminology for the definition of a function.

> A function from set $A$ to set $B$, denoted by
>   $$f:A\to B;x\mapsto f(x)$$
>   is a mapping of elements from set $A$, (the $\textit{domain}$) to elements in set $B$ (the $\textit{codomain}$) using the $\color{blue}{\sf function}$ $f(x)$. The domain of a function is the set of all valid elements for a function to map from. The codomain of a function is the set of all possible values that an element from the domain can be mapped to. The $\textit{range}$ (sometimes called the $\textit{image}$) of a function is a subset of the codomain, and is the set of all elements that actually get mapped to by the function $f$.

Here I'm pretty sure the highlighted word "function" is not right.

Comment: I suggest \to or \rightarrow instead of \longrightarrow.  The last one is there for if you need the arrow to be longer because you're writing something over it.  As in $\overset{\text{text}}{\longrightarrow}$ instead of $\overset{\text{text}}{\to}$.

Comment: why do you think that function is not right =

Comment: Some would call "$f(x)=x^2$"  the *rule* of the function $f$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Well, function is used in two places to mean two slightly different things; I don't like using function to describe part of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can remember to read this text, and being puzzled with the exact same question. From what I've learned from my teacher, you're right, writing down something as "the function $f(x)$..."  is sloppy notation. However, many books/people will use it this way.

If you're are very precise, $f(x)$ is **not** a function or an map. I don't know of a standard way to refer to $f(x)$, but here is some usage I found on the internet:

- The **output** of a function $f$ corresponding to an input $x$ is denoted by $f(x)$.
- Some would call "$f(x)=x^2$" the **rule** of the function $f$.
- For each argument $x$, the corresponding unique $y$ in the codomain is called the **function value** at $x$ or the image of $x$ under $f$. It is written as $f(x)$.
- If there is some relation specifying $f(x)$ in terms of $x$, then $f(x)$ is known as a **dependent variable** (and $x$ is an independent variable).

A correct way to notate your function $f$ is:
$$f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}:x\mapsto f(x)=x^2$$

Note that $f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f\not\in\Bbb{R}$. But the function $f$ is an element of the set of continuous functions, and $f(x)$ isn't.

In some areas of math it is very important to notate a function/map specifying it's domain, codomain and function rule. However in for example calculus/physics, you'll see that many times only the function rule $f(x)$ is specified, as the reader is supposed to understand domain/codmain from the context.

You can also check those questions:

- [In written mathematics, is $f(x)$a function or a number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/in-written-mathematics-is-fx-a-function-or-a-number)
- [What is the difference between writing f and f(x)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276650/what-is-the-difference-between-writing-f-and-fx)

Comment: Nice, Kasper +1

Answer (score 1):

normally you say $f:X\rightarrow Y$; $x\mapsto f(x)$, as a functions takes an element from $X$ and give you one from $Y$. 
$$y=f(x)$$ 
Is an equation, and not a definition of a function in a strict sense.

The proper way would be $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \ x\mapsto x^2$$

The Image of a function is definied as 
$$\operatorname{im}f:=\{f(x)|x\in X\}$$
It is often written as 
$$f(X):=\{f(x)|x\in X\}$$
Notice that $X$ is a set, not an element.
so $f(\{x\})=\{f(x)\}\subseteq Y$ while $f(x)\in Y$

Comment: I was wondering - is $f(x)$ called the image? I've seen that word used but only know it to be synonymous with Range.

Comment: not $f(x)$ but $f(X)$ note the different as $X$ is a set but $x$ is an element

Comment: @agent154 You can say "$f(x)$ is the image of the element $x$ under the function $f$". Perhaps this is what you were thinking of (here of course "image" means something different than the image of the function).

Comment: @davidMitra i would be careful with that, as the image is a set but $f(x)$ is an element of $Y$

Comment: The notation $f(X)$ is also written (in set theory) as $f[X]$ and $f''X$ sometimes, often because the elements of the set are sets themselves, and sometimes $f(x)\neq f''x$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis This terminology, though perhaps unfortunate, is standard  in the U.S. (in undergraduate courses at least). "image" has at least two distinct meanings. That is: the image of a set, $f(\{x\})$, and the image (value) of a member of the domain under $f$, $f(x)$.

Comment: As a non native speaker my first idea was the value of the function $f$ for $x$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis What is the symbol $:=$?

Comment: @agent154 it says that something is defined.

Comment: who downvoted ?

Answer (score -3):

From what I understand, $f$ is the function, so saying "a function $f(x)$" would 
be wrong. Instead, you could say "a function $f$", or if you didn't want to assign it a name, "a function $x\mapsto x^2$", or if you want to specify the domain and codomain, "a function $f:X\to Y$".

If you just want to define the function's input-output relationship, $f(x)=x^2$ suffices, maybe with a $\forall x\in X$ at the beginning if you want to do it properly. That doesn't necessarily define the domain though, that set could just be a subset of the domain. $f(x)$ is really no different from $f(1)$, except that $x$ is a (qualified) variable. It's basically a rule defining the input and output for an improper subset of its domain.

The addition of "$:X\to Y$" is useful if you want to specify both the domain and codomain when defining the function. As far as I can tell, you can add it after a function like $f$ and the whole expression still refers to the function. You can't really use it with the $f(x)$ style, so I'd do something like

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R=x\mapsto x^2$